# interval of convergence of $\sum$ $\sqrt n$ $x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Basically question is the title: Find the interval of convergence of power series $\sum$ $\sqrt n$ $x^n$

I have the solution and it says it should be $(-1,1)$ but I cant figure out the $x = -1$ case

I first find the radius:

$R$ = $\lim_n$ ($|a_n|$/$|a_{n+1}|$) = $\lim_n$ $\sqrt{n}$/$\sqrt{n+1}$ = $\lim_n$ $1$/$\sqrt {1 + (1/n)}$ = $1$

Then I check $x = 1$:

$\sum$$\sqrt n$ $1^n$ = $\sum$$\sqrt n$ = $\infty$

so the sum diverges for $x = 1$. I check $x = -1$ now:

$\sum$$\sqrt n$ $(-1)^n$

I identify that the alternating series test doesn't work here since $\sqrt n$ is not decreasing. I use the Ratio Test to identify if a series $\sum a_n$ diverges or converges, since here we have $a_n = \sqrt n (-1)^n $ is nonzero for all $n$, but I eventually see that this test, as well as the root test, is inconclusive.

Any help would be cool, thanks.

Comment: Does $\sqrt{n}(-1)^n$ converge to $0$?

Comment: pretty sure it doesnt, as $\sqrt n$ is increasing. The sequence would oscillate, going from $1$,$ - \sqrt 2$, $\sqrt 3$, $- \sqrt 4$, ... and so on

Comment: if a sequence is convergent to a limit $L$, then any of its subsequences must converge to the same limit $L$.

Comment: Can't you conclude anything from the summed sequence not converging to 0?

Comment: Ohhhhhh wow now I feel incredibly stupid. If $\lim a_n \ne 0$ or is divergent then $\sum a_n$ diverges. Thanks